# passport-github how to extract session cookie to know that the user already logged in

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am building a passport-github auth to my application. but I think currently I don't know how to extract the cookie from request that would say user is already logged in. so everytime When i go to home page i get redirected to /login.

My code roughly looks like this:

```
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
    clientID: authConfig.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: authConfig.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/github/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    return db.user.findOne({where:{github_id:profile.id}})
    .then(data=>{
      if (data) {
        return done(null,data);
      } else {
        return db.user.build({ github_id: profile.id }).save()
        .then(()=>{
          return db.user.findOne({where:{github_id:profile.id}})
        })
        .then(data=>{
          return done(null,data);
        })
      }
    });
  }
));

// Passport session setup.
//   To support persistent login sessions, Passport needs to be able to
//   serialize users into and deserialize users out of the session.  Typically,
//   this will be as simple as storing the user ID when serializing, and finding
//   the user by ID when deserializing
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log("serialize>>>>>", user.github_id);
  done(null, user.github_id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  console.log("deserialize>>>>", id);
  db.user.findOne({where:{github_id: id}})
  .then(user=>{
    done(null, user.toJSON());
  })
});
```

I have established the session :

```
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

And I have an isAuthenticated function that checks for req info:

```
function isAuthenticated (req, res, next) {
  // If the user is logged in, continue with the request to the restricted route
  console.log("req.user is>>>>", req);
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  // If the user isnt' logged in, redirect them to the login page
  return res.redirect("/index");
}
```

I am using this passport-github lib. I cannot get some useful information from `req`seems

updated to include routes:
Here is the routes:

```
    const isAuthenticated = require('./middleware/isAuthenticated.js');
router
    .get('/index', query.renderIndex)
    .get('/', isAuthenticated, query.displayRepos)
    .post('/', query.queryRepoTopic)
    .post('/trending', query.addRepo)
    .post('/addTopic', query.addTopic)
    .get('trending', query.updateScore);

router.get('/login', auth.loginPage)
  .get('/auth/github',
    passport.authenticate('github', { scope: [ 'user:email' ] }),
    function(req, res){}
  )
  .get('/auth/github/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    auth.signInRedirect
  )
  .get('/logout', auth.logout);
```

Here is the controller function that does the logic:

```
const loginPage = (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
}

// signin a user in 
const signInRedirect = (req, res) => {
  console.log("here in callback>>>");
  console.log("req.user is>>>>", req.user);
  //res.json("you have successfully logged in!");
  res.redirect('/');
}

const logout = (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/index');
}
```

Comment: Could you put more details about your routes?

Comment: what does the `auth.loginPage` do? Could you provide its code to?

Comment: it's just this: 
const loginPage = (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
}

rendering the login page, which has a "login" button.

Comment: Hm... where does your code call the `isAuthenticated` function?

Comment: updated routes.

Comment: Ok. When do you call the `/auth/github` route? To be logged in, you need to call this route frst, and then you'll be redirected to the github authentication page and then, you are logged in. Are you doing it?

Comment: I think calling `auth/github` only happens in the "/index" page where there's a button with href="/auth/github". I see what you saying.... i am not exactly sure how to deal with it? if I load the address "http://localhost:3000", how would that automatically trigger a call to "/auth/github" endpoint,?

Comment: I guess inside "isAuthenticate" function, we can call this function `passport.authenticate('github', { scope: [ 'user:email' ] })` again if it doesn't find req.isAuthenticated() ?

Comment: See my answer, I think it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have this route configuration:

```
    const isAuthenticated = require('./middleware/isAuthenticated.js');
    router
        .get('/index', query.renderIndex)
        .get('/', isAuthenticated, query.displayRepos)
...
```

If you want to call `localhost:3000`, and be redirected to `auth/github` when you are not logged in, you could change `isAuthenticated function` like this:

```
function isAuthenticated (req, res, next) {
  // If the user is logged in, continue with the request to the restricted route
  console.log("req.user is>>>>", req);
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  // If the user isnt' logged in, redirect them to the github login page.
  return res.redirect("/auth/github");
}
```

Wich means, when you try to call the `'/'`, the `isAuthenticated`  will check if the `req.user` was set (`if (req.isAuthenticated())`), if not, redirect to the `/auth/github` route.

Have you tried this?

Have it can help!